# Cannot call a method using a shortcut

Tags: ruby

I have a module that defines a method to log some output in an html file. The module looks like this:

```
module Htmllog
  @htmllogfile = "htmllog/myproject" + Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.html'

  def self.add(text, tag)
    if tag.length == 0
      formattedlog = text
    else
      formattedlog = "<#{tag}>#{text}</#{tag}>"
      puts text
    end 
    File.open(@htmllogfile, "a") do |f| 
      f.puts formattedlog
    end 
  end 
end
```

I call it in my main.rb file and it works just fine if I call it like this:

```
Htmllog.add "Hello world!", "h1"
```

Since I have to log a lot of stuff, I want to add a shortcut to reduce the number of digits and I tried this:

```
l = Htmllog.add
l "Hello world!", "h1"
```

But I get this error.

```
`add': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: you `l = Htmllog.add` is expecting the arguments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as below using [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [`Method#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-call):

```
l = Htmllog.method(:add)
l.call("Hello world!", "h1")
l.("Hello world!", "h1") # which is same l.call("Hello world!", "h1")
```

`l = Htmllog.add` is not valid as per the your method definition of `add`. So you got error.

Comment: You can go `l[...]` instead of `l.call(...)`, if you want it shorter. Ruby doesn't permit method referencing in a variable, probably because it would cause syntactic ambiguity since it's possible to call a method without paranthesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `l` to be available globally, then you should define that as a method on `Kernel`.

```
module Kernel
  def l *args; Htmllog.add(*args) end
end

l "Hello world!", "h1"
```

Be careful not to have a conflict with existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

1 When ruby sees `l = Htmllog.add` , it will first run `Htmllog.add` with no argument, and then give the result to variable `l`. That's why you have this error.

2 One way you can do it is to use an anonymous function :

```
l = ->(text, tag) { Htmllog.add(text, tag) }
```